# Prolog: Asking the user for a value only if it is not known

Tags: prolog

I want to write a KB that, when attempting to prove a goal, will ask the user for input if it doesn't have a value for a specific sub-goal. For instance, consider the following:
possible goals:

```
blue(X) :-
    color(X,blue).
white(X) :-
    color(X,white).
yellow(X) :-
    color(X,yellow).
orange(X) :-
    color(X,orange).
red(X) :-
    color(X,red).
```

Asking for input:

```
askColor(X,Y) :- 
                write('color of  '),write(X),tab(2),
                read(Z),
                asserta(color(X,Z)),
                Y==Z. %only return "true" if the asserted color is the one we're looking for.
% trying to do "if we know the color is not Y, fail. otherwise (if we don't have a value for the color) ask the user". however, it always asks the user :(
color(X,Y) :- atom(Y), ((Z\=Y,atom(Z), color(X,Z)) -> fail ; askColor(X,Y)).
```

The desired result would be this:

- user enters `blue(name).` since the color of "name" is unknown, we ask the user. if the user enters "blue", `color(name, blue)` is stored in the KB and we get "true" as a result (we assume this in the next steps). If anything else is entered, it stores the info and returns "false". this seems to work properly.
- future queries for `blue(name)` or `color(name,blue)` immediately return "true", as expected.
- now where things go wrong:

  - future calls to `color(name,Y)` return `Y=blue` as a solution, however it also asks for user input.
  - calls to `red(name)` or `color(name, red)` still ask the user for input. they should instead immediately return "false" because `color(name,blue)` is known and "blue" is not equal to "red".

I understand that for this particular example, it may make more sense to ask the user to pick in a menu between a set of supported values (I have code for that). However, some other parts of my program will need to do the same for integers, which must support any value.

Comment: This is a very outdated style of Prolog programs. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/) that covers that style quite well. I am not sure if you will find the exact same built-ins, but all Prologs have the functionality used in this tutorial in some form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be these facts are useful:

```
:- dynamic db_color/2.

color(X,Y) :-
  db_color(X,Y).

color(X,_) :-
  db_color(X,_), !, fail.

color(X,Y) :-
  write('color of  '),write(X),tab(2),
  read(Z),
  asserta(db_color(X,Z)),
  Y=Z.
```

some queries and results:

```
?- color(apple,blue).
color of  apple  red.

false.

?- color(apple,blue).
false.

?- color(apple,red).
true ;
false.

?- color(apple,X).
X = red ;
false.

?- color(X,blue).
false.

?- color(X,red).
X = apple ;
false.

?- color(X,Y).
X = apple,
Y = red ;
false
```

Comment: from what I understand, there needs to be a separate predicate for storing user input?